# Why are graphics so slow/jerky/lagged with an ATI 4250?

Tags: 11.04, graphics, ati, fglrx

Never had a problem with Maverick, always very fast. I upgrade to Natty and the graphics seem to be very lagged. CPU, load, and memory usage is low, all graphics are choppy and lagged though. I have the proprietary driver installed and everything.

Alt-Tabbing takes 3-5 seconds for the dialog to popup, zooming in with compiz zoom makes things very slow. I never had any of these problems with 10.10

Comment: Have you tried it without fglrx?

Answer (score 2):

Hey, if you install compizconfig you can try unchecking the V-Blank in general options, as in the open-source ATI driver in natty there is already V-sync activated. It did the trick for me so you can try it

Answer (score 2):

In ubuntu 11.04 the setting is located on ccsm>OpenGL>Sync to VBlank. When fglrx is enabled, this should be unchecked otherwise performance is sluggish and slow.

Answer (score 1):

try the latest [amd-ati-catalyst-114](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/amd-ati-catalyst-114-released-just-in.html)

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem, but using this info solved it:
http://www.linuxinsight.com/your-ati-radeon-very-slow-on-xorg-x-server-1.3.html
Now my Ubuntu is snappy beyond my imagination

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.