# Graphics very jerky on Natty Narwal

Tags: 11.04, graphics, ati, performance

I just got a new laptop, and installed narwal on it.  Things like youtube videso play fine, however "system graphics" (for lack of a better term) are extremely jerky, for example closing a tab will take several seconds, or even typing in this text box gets several seconds behind where I am typing.  My system hardware is pretty beefy, so it's not a hardware issue: Intel Quad core 2GHz, 8GB of RAM, and a radeon 6570M with 1GB (running the proprietary driver).

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but usually things like this happens in a freshly released distribution. Since you just got the laptop, try installing 10.04 LTS instead or wait until 11.04 becomes stable. (Patches are submitted overtime to solve problems like this)

Comment: I've run Ubuntu alphas for the last few releases, so I'm used to the gradual stabilization.  I'm trying to establish if this is known bug (that I could follow), something I should report, or a case of "twiddle these settings".

Comment: A different ATI VGA but symptoms are somewhat similar http://askubuntu.com/questions/36182/why-are-graphics-so-slow-jerky-lagged-with-an-ati-4250

Comment: What about the opensource driver? My nvidia runs better with nouveau.

Comment: You might consider "upgrading" to the latest build of Natty Narwhale later today when it gets released.  What theme are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the latest [amd-ati-catalyst-114](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/04/amd-ati-catalyst-114-released-just-in.html)

Comment: This seems to have helped, though not solved the problem completely.  The problem also appears to be minimized by using Chromium in place of Firefox.

Answer (score 1):

In compizconfig settings manager, go into openGL (under general options) and uncheck the option that says "Sync To VBlank". This is what worked for me, and a friend of mine.

Answer (score 1):

### Disable Detect Refresh Rate, and Sync To Vblank

- Install **CompizConfig SettingsManager**
  by running the following command in a
  terminal:

  `sudo apt-get install
  compizconfig-settings-manager`
- Launch it by searching from the dash
  in Unity, or find it under
  **Preferences > CompizConfig Settings
  Manager** in Ubuntu Classic.
- Click on the **Composite** tab, and
  un-check Detect refresh rate.
  [image]
  [image]
- Click on the **OpenGL** tab, and un-check
  Sync to Vblank.
  [image]
  [image]